# Sudden drop of score in the last few episodes

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMZfgeHFFcA&t=3s) about lunar lander and deep Q learning with Tensorflow 2 and I noticed something odd.

The problem was actually solved at episode 476 but then the score went from 259.90 to -520.33 and stayed negative until the last episode 500.

```
episode:  468  score 248.95 average score 188.47 epsilon 0.01
episode:  469  score 269.47 average score 192.11 epsilon 0.01
episode:  470  score 225.31 average score 195.72 epsilon 0.01
episode:  471  score 46.36 average score 194.66 epsilon 0.01
episode:  472  score 250.61 average score 198.44 epsilon 0.01
episode:  473  score 237.25 average score 198.50 epsilon 0.01
episode:  474  score 237.02 average score 202.16 epsilon 0.01
episode:  475  score 249.85 average score 204.11 epsilon 0.01
episode:  476  score 259.90 average score 204.15 epsilon 0.01
episode:  477  score -520.33 average score 198.10 epsilon 0.01
episode:  478  score -567.86 average score 190.58 epsilon 0.01
episode:  479  score -670.45 average score 185.15 epsilon 0.01
episode:  480  score -413.31 average score 178.85 epsilon 0.01
episode:  481  score -995.13 average score 166.78 epsilon 0.01
episode:  482  score -450.73 average score 159.52 epsilon 0.01
episode:  483  score -583.07 average score 151.16 epsilon 0.01
episode:  484  score -586.59 average score 143.61 epsilon 0.01
episode:  485  score -436.80 average score 136.45 epsilon 0.01
episode:  486  score -665.69 average score 127.73 epsilon 0.01
episode:  487  score -602.49 average score 119.65 epsilon 0.01
episode:  488  score -1685.73 average score 99.95 epsilon 0.01
episode:  489  score -689.85 average score 91.23 epsilon 0.01
episode:  490  score -501.80 average score 83.63 epsilon 0.01
episode:  491  score -1016.14 average score 74.79 epsilon 0.01
episode:  492  score -475.65 average score 67.81 epsilon 0.01
episode:  493  score -525.98 average score 59.80 epsilon 0.01
episode:  494  score -393.08 average score 53.57 epsilon 0.01
episode:  495  score -557.32 average score 46.85 epsilon 0.01
episode:  496  score -431.39 average score 39.88 epsilon 0.01
episode:  497  score -944.19 average score 27.72 epsilon 0.01
episode:  498  score -571.92 average score 19.96 epsilon 0.01
episode:  499  score -498.09 average score 14.63 epsilon 0.01
```

What happened?

Is it overfitting?

Is it normal?

Does it mean that we have to run fewer episodes or run it again?

I'm confused about how to test different models and hyperparameters.

Here's the full code

```
import gym 
import numpy as np 
import tensorflow as tf 
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam 
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

class ReplayBuffer():
    def __init__(self, memory_size, input_dims):
        self.memory_size = memory_size
        self.memory_counter = 0

        self.state_memory = np.zeros((self.memory_size, *input_dims), dtype=np.float32)
        self.new_state_memory = np.zeros((self.memory_size, *input_dims), dtype=np.float32)

        self.action_memory = np.zeros(self.memory_size, dtype=np.int32)
        self.reward_memory = np.zeros(self.memory_size, dtype=np.float32)
        self.terminal_memory = np.zeros(self.memory_size, dtype=np.int32)

    def store_transition(self, state, action, reward, new_state, done):
        index = self.memory_counter % self.memory_size
        self.state_memory[index] = state
        self.new_state_memory[index] = new_state
        self.reward_memory[index] = reward
        self.action_memory[index] = action
        self.terminal_memory[index] = 1 - int(done)
        self.memory_counter += 1
    
    def sample_buffer(self, batch_size):
        max_memory = min(self.memory_counter, self.memory_size)
        batch = np.random.choice(max_memory, batch_size, replace=False)

        states = self.state_memory[batch]
        new_state = self.new_state_memory[batch]
        rewards = self.reward_memory[batch]
        actions = self.action_memory[batch]
        terminal = self.terminal_memory[batch]

        return states, actions, new_state, rewards, terminal

def build_dqn(learning_rate, number_actions, input_dims, fully_connected1_dims, fully_connected2_dims):
    model = keras.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Dense(fully_connected1_dims, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(fully_connected2_dims, activation='relu'),
        keras.layers.Dense(number_actions, activation=None)
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model

class Agent():
    def __init__(self, learning_rate, gamma, number_actions, epsilon, batch_size, input_dims, 
                epsilon_dec=1e-3, epsilon_end=0.01, memory_size=1000000, file_name='dn_model.h5'):
        
        self.action_space = [i for i in range(number_actions)]
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.epsilon_dec = epsilon_dec
        self.epsilon_minimum = epsilon_end
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.model_file = file_name
        self.memory = ReplayBuffer(memory_size, input_dims)
        self.q_eval = build_dqn(learning_rate, number_actions, input_dims, 256, 256)
    
    def store_transition(self, state, action, reward, new_state, done):
        self.memory.store_transition(state, action, reward, new_state, done)

    def choose_action(self, observation):
        if np.random.random() < self.epsilon:
            action = np.random.choice(self.action_space)
        else: 
            state = np.array([observation])
            actions = self.q_eval.predict(state)

            action = np.argmax(actions)
        return action

    def learn(self):
        if self.memory.memory_counter < self.batch_size:
            return
        
        states, actions, new_states, rewards, dones = self.memory.sample_buffer(self.batch_size)

        q_eval = self.q_eval.predict(states)
        q_next = self.q_eval.predict(new_states)

        q_target = np.copy(q_eval)
        batch_index = np.arange(self.batch_size, dtype=np.int32)

        q_target[batch_index, actions] = rewards + self.gamma * np.max(q_next, axis=1) * dones

        self.q_eval.train_on_batch(states, q_target)

        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_minimum: 
            self.epsilon = self.epsilon - self.epsilon_dec 
        else:
            self.epsilon = self.epsilon_minimum
        
    def save_model(self):
        self.q_eval.save(self.model_file)

    def load_model(self):
        self.q_eval = load_model(self.model_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
    environment = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
    learning_rate = 0.001
    number_games = 500
    agent = Agent(gamma=0.99, epsilon=1.0, learning_rate=learning_rate, 
                    input_dims=environment.observation_space.shape, number_actions=environment.action_space.n, memory_size=1000000, batch_size=64, 
                    epsilon_end=0.01)
    scores = []
    epsilon_history = []

    for i in range(number_games):
        done = False
        score = 0
        observation = environment.reset()
        while not done:
            action = agent.choose_action(observation)
            new_observation, reward, done, info = environment.step(action)
            score += reward
            agent.store_transition(observation, action, reward, new_observation, done)
            observation = new_observation
            agent.learn()

            if i % 100 == 0:
                environment.render()
            
        epsilon_history.append(agent.epsilon)
        scores.append(score)

        average_score = np.mean(scores[-100:])
        print('episode: ', i, ' score %.2f' % score, 
            'average score %.2f' % average_score, 
            'epsilon %.2f' % agent.epsilon)
```

Comment: Is it a better practice to stop to learn once the problem is solved?